# Github Branch revert

Tags: git, version-control, github

So I made a push to my branch that I was happy with.

Then afterwards (on local) I made some changes. I don't like the changes, how do I revert back to the last push I made to the branch?

I tried 'git pull github branchname', but that seems to have messed up my local work even more and gave me response:
`* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
git log
```

(which gets a log of what's been committed & pushed... it may look something like this:

```
commit ed0787d4c3375bfa2158506ea3d49402cbde9db1
Author: Michael <nobody@umich.edu>
Date:   Tue Apr 22 08:26:02 2014 -0700

    Replace two assets

    two assets were PSD instead of PNG. Fixed.
```

now, there will be a whole list of these commits.  I'll use the above listing as my "last good" commit ID, and with that, you can do this:

```
git reset --hard ed0787d4c3375bfa2158506ea3d49402cbde9db1
```

(the number is the commit ID where you want to erase your branch to)

```
git log
```

(make sure it looks good)

```
git remote -v

git push -f origin HEAD
```

(save your changes!)

Comment: Generally speaking, using destructive commands (rebase, reset filter-branch etc.) on published history is a bad idea. However, if you're the only one who's pushing to this public branch, Michaels suggestion would be what I'd do too.

Comment: Right... what I didn't put in my answer was how to make a backup branch, just in case I bollux things up in the process.

Comment: My only concern is the last two commands, what exactly are they doing?   BTW my last push/commit WAS good, my issue is getting the files up to par on local again(AKA making my local look like the last commit I made). Is this still the best way to do that? I am a little confused here.

Comment: I'm not sure you need a "backup branch" either. The reflog will have the previous commits and you can always reset back to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here the situation as I understand it.
You've got one remote branch where everything is ok.
You 've got one local commit where things got wrong.

I see two options:

1. **reset --hard to the previous good commit**.

How to find the good commit ?

`git log -10`

display the history of you current branch on your last 10 commits.

or

`git reflog -10`

display the history of last ten moves of your HEAD (i.e what you've done, no matter the branch)
Once the commit spotted:

`git reset --hard [commit_sha1]`

Five first sha1 char are enough.

2 **We don't mind your local branch**.

Indeed you remote branch is good. So why bother ?

`git checkout -b [remote_name]/[branch_name]`

How to know the remote name ?

`git remote`

branch name ? 

`git branch -r`

e.g: git checkout -b origin/foo

If you're pleased with your new branch, then delete the old one.

`git branch -D [old_branch]`

Comment: Ok, I hard reset, but that didn't change anything locally.Local still doesn't look right. It is missing a ton of files that I know are on the branch. My local is totally messed up right now, and I know the master and branch are still good.

Comment: @ApathyBear, so let's try the second option, i.e checkout your remote branch. You want to be synched with your remote branch ? Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the last (which means there happened no further commit on the same branch) commit is pretty easy.

You may add changes to the last commit by invoking [`git commit --amend`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) which adds your current changes the last commit.

You also could "unpack" your last commit into the current working branch (which implys your current changes get lost) by invoking `git reset --hard`.

I'd like to suggest you reading the [branch chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) of pro git for further understanding of branches and commits. Another helpful resource is this interactive [cheat-sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=workspace;).

Answer (score 0):

If `github/branchname` is what you want your local branch to be at, then just do:

```
git reset --hard github/branchname
```

Just keep in mind that `git reset --hard` will **drop commits**--which is what you want in this case--but keep it at the forefront of your mind.  It's an easy way to lose work, if you aren't careful.  If you do make a mistake, `git reflog` can give you a list of sha1s that used to be the tip of your branch, and you can use it to restore your state.